# What is the difference between exciting an electron to a higher bound state and removing it completely (ionizing the atom)?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, ionization-energy

We are reviewing quantum mechanics and orbitals in my class and I'm confused about the energies to move an electron to an excited state vs. remove it from an atom.
Even though the electron on a H atom occupies the 1s orbital in ground state, it can be excited to the 2s orbital, 2p, etc. and each transition has an amount of energy it requires. We also learned that it takes -13.6eV to remove that electron from the H atom entirely.

If all the higher orbital states are still possible for the electron in the H atom (and the last electron in a polyelectronic atom?), at what point is the electron removed and not just excited to higher and higher energy states? If it's removed when it no longer interacts with the nucleus, does that mean there is a finite number of energy states/orbitals an electron can occupy before it's not interacting anymore? I have a feeling this might be really simple and it's just not "clicking" yet.

Comment: We do not really understand what you are looking for. The number of energy states an electron can occupy is infinite. But high energy states are more and more close together, just before the electron is not interacting any more with the nucleus. So what is the problem ?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more a physics question than a chemistry question

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the simplest atom (hydrogen) with the simplest model (Bohr model). The energy of the electron with a principal quantum number $n$ is:

$$ E = \frac{\pu{-13.6 eV }}{ n^2}$$

So the lowest (most tightly bound) electron has an energy of -13.6 eV. This is relative to the unbound electron (which defines a potential energy of zero). So if you excite with more than 13.6 eV, the electron will no longer be bound (the excess energy is "used" as kinetic energy). If you excite with less, it will still be bound. Notice that when you go to higher and higher $n$, the expression for the energy approaches zero.

Here is a diagram that illustrates this:

[image]

Source: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Lumen_Learning/Book%3A_General_Chemistry__Lecture_and_Lab_(Lumen)/05%3A_Electronic_Structure_and_Periodic_Properties_of_Elements/5.03%3A_The_Bohr_Model